# What's the difference between "up that street" and "down that street"?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, difference

> To walk down that Street (sense-Along)

> To walk up that street (Sense-Along)

Are both the sentences the same in meaning?

Comment: not entirely related, but in the UK certain places (especially London, and the universities of Oxford and Cambridge) are traditionally places you only ever go/come up to (even though all are in the South with plenty of locations to their North one might come from and London & Cambridge are both low-lying and so you're likely to have approached them from higher ground), and when leaving them you're said to going/coming down from (and in the case of Oxford and Cambridge "being sent down" means to be expelled)

Comment: @Tristan Are you sure Brits never go [down to London?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNoOLCsqNTE)

Comment: @Davislor as I said, "traditionally". It's definitely not unusual to hear about someone going down to London these days

Comment: Up that street is where it is. But you have to go down the road to get there.

Comment: If you're in Edinburgh, you'd definitely say "I'm going DOWN to London"

Comment: This is nothing to do with the question but I think the "Up to London" and down to somewhere else may have origins in the railway world (in the UK).  This is on the edge of my memory, but I think the two lines (where there were two parallel tracks between the same two points) were called the Up Line and the Down Line.   But perhaps the naming of the lines or tracks followed the convention in Tristan's comment.

Comment: @Flynn they still are called that and where there are four they are usually slow down, slow up, fast down and fast up.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Taken completely out of context, the two sentences are semantically identical (that is, they mean the exact same thing).

However, nothing is ever completely lacking in context. The ‘normal’ meaning in context depends on a bunch of different factors, and could be any of the following:

- ‘up’ versus ‘down’ indicates uphill versus downhill. This does not always map to actual elevation, and may just be based on relative perception based on where the person is going (for example, if I’m walking along a street to go to a beach, I would almost always use ‘down’, because I’ve spent most of my life significantly above sea level and just think about the ocean as ‘down’ relative to me, no matter where I am).
- ‘up’ versus ‘down’ indicates specific compass directions in reference to the orientation of a map (usually North for up and South for down, but not always).
- ‘up’ versus ‘down’ indicates direction relative to some specific location. This may refer to the local city center (often called ‘downtown’ in many parts of the English speaking world), the most expensive district of the city (sometimes, but not always, called ‘uptown’), or even just some other specific place.

That said, there is one thing that is generally consistent: When talking about walking along a street to a specific place, the choice of ‘up’ or ‘down’ will often mirror which of ‘I walked up to X’ or ‘I walked down to X’ would be used by local speakers to describe going to that place. This will *usually* map to one of the above cases as well, but not always.

Comment: It's kind of like the modifiers used for the 4 cardinal map directions.  Just as you might hear "up north" or "down south" due to the traditional orientation of maps, you might (in the US at least) hear "out west" or "back east", for obvious historical reasons, but this probably wouldn't work in other locations.  (Though I have also heard "out west" from Australians, so at least that one seems to have similar usage.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: Australia is similar to the US in that its larger and earlier-established population centers are on the east coast.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman the UK has "up North" (sometimes spelt in eye dialect as "oop North") and "down South", but doesn't have "back East" or "out West", likely because whilst English settlement did start in the East and gradually spread West, it did so well over a millennium ago so isn't really still in the public consciousness

Comment: we also don't have an especially strong cultural East/West divide, which likely helps the lack of specific set phrases. The West Country is reasonably well understood as a distinct region of the South, but the West & East Midlands are not especially distinct, and whilst the Northeast & Northwest have sporting rivalries based on the Wars of the Roses, the cultural differences are very small compared to those between the North & South

Comment: You missed the distinction of whether the house numbers are increasing (up) or decreasing (down) in that direction.

Comment: @OrangeDog That could vary greatly based on location.  Some will go down until you get to the center of the city, then start going up on the other side.  Others are strictly increasing going east->west or north->south or maybe the reverse of that.  There are some places where the numbers go up on one side of the street and down on the other.  (I guess so you can always tell how far you are from the end of the street?)  Sometimes #1 will just be the oldest or largest/richest building on the street, regardless of location.  It can be very confusing.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman same as all the other meanings

Comment: I am originally from a city in upstate NY and the typical way of saying you are going to Lake Ontario is to say you are going "down to the lake." The lake is due north, so one anecdote in favor of the "elevation" bullet point.

Comment: In my experience in Canada, going "out West" is something people from the east do.  You go "out West" for work, and "back East" when you are going back home.

Comment: @JMac Not surprising that would be the case in Canada as well, for the same reason as the US and Australia.  The eastern parts of all three countries were settled first (by Europeans at least - not sure if the native tribes that were there first would agree).

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I really dont think it is about the history of the nation as much as it is about where you consider home.  Someone from Alberta would probably not call Nova Scotia "back East", for example.

Answer (score 29):

"Up the street" and "down the street" are very similar, and can mean the exact same thing. There are some situations where one is preferred over the other, though none of these are strict rules.

We prefer "up" if the direction is roughly North or if it is uphill. And conversely, we prefer "down" if the direction is roughly South or is downhill.

We also prefer "up" if the direction is *towards* something, and "down" if the direction is *away* from something.

> To get to MOMA, go **up** 53rd Street. It's just past 5th Ave.

> He said goodbye and walked off **down** the street.

Another preference is to use "down" if the direction it towards a "downtown" area of the city, and "up" if the direction is away from a "downtown" area.

Like I said, none of these are rules, so I *could* be pointing up a hill, facing North, and give someone directions away from downtown saying, "Go **down** this street...", and it would only be a little bit odd.

Comment: Don't forget that in many cities "uptown" is the hoity-toity residential area.

Comment: I don't think it would occur to me to associate up vs down with north vs south.  The bit about uphill vs downhill is the only part of this answer that would apply to me.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I agree with you. The part about toward and away isn't true either. It's completely natural to say "go down that street" when giving directions, and they're certainly going towards their destination (anyone going anywhere is both going towards something and away from something, for that matter).

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I could see it if talking about it while referencing a map, but not in general.

Comment: Ah, I have the habit of holding maps the wrong way round.  In my mental model of the city I live in, West is up.

Comment: @Thierry By towards and away of "something", I don't think they meant the person's destination, but rather something like the city center or other popular spots where most daytime traffic in a street typically heads toward.

Comment: @HotLicks Only in some parts of the world.  In the UK, the central business/admin district is usually called the ‘_town/city centre_’, and you might talk about going _into town_ or _out of town_. ‘Uptown’ and ‘downtown’ don't have any special meaning; you'd probably interpret them in the same ways as ‘up/down the street’.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Opposite for me, North/South is the only way I distinguish between 'up' and 'down' terms.

Comment: I think your example also bring up another association: street numbers. For example if a named street intersects numbered streets, I believe some speakers will associate up with the direction in which numbered streets increase. If you're standing at Walnut and 30th street, you're "walking up towards 40th" or "down towards 10th".